# Controlgroup: 3 buttons horizontal, multiple rows on JQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Using JQuery Mobile v1.4.3 with JQuery 1.11
I'm dynamically adding layers to a canvas using KinectJS.
I'm working on a layer control to move and hide layers.
I'm thinking of using the controlgroup for this. I can add 4 horizontal buttons/links which look great.
But when adding a new layer I need to add below the first 4 horizontal buttons again a series of 4 buttons.
I can't get this to work.
I tried adding a controlgroup for each layer, but then I can't dynamically add elements to it. It throws an exception about the controlgroup not initialized.

So how can I get buttons like this:

```
(link|link|link|link)
(link|link|link|link)
(link|link|link|link)
```

I've added a simple test on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/okL0geuw/2/
When you hit the button it appends the 4 links to the previous one. But it should add them on a new line.
BTW. I'm still working on getting the styling working in the fiddle sample.

Comment: Can you do a demo on fiddle to look.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I updated my post with the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All buttons in a horizontal *controlgroup* have `float: left` and `clear: none`. To force new added buttons to jump to next line, you need to `clear: left` of only first button of each new group of buttons.

You may also update `margin-bottom` to make each set look like a separate group.

Then, to maintain *controlgroup*'s UI, you need to add `ui-first-child` to every first button and `ui-last-child` class to every fourth button after *refreshing*. Note that you don't need to call `.enhanceWithin()` after adding new element, `.controlgroup("refresh")` is enough.

```css
.ui-controlgroup .ui-btn:nth-child(4n+1) {
   clear:left;
}

.ui-controlgroup .ui-btn {
   margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```js
$el = "<buttons>";
$("#layercontrol")
    .controlgroup("container")
    .append($el)
    .end()
    .controlgroup("refresh")
    .find(".ui-btn:nth-child(4n)")
    .addClass("ui-last-child")
    .end()
    .find(".ui-btn:nth-child(4n+1)")
    .addClass("ui-first-child");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Lh7ynwhw/)**

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for all evening.

Comment: @PaulMeems you're welcome. I've updated my answer as well as the demo.

Comment: @Tasos I do prefer CSS ;)

Comment: @Omar and Tasos I've added a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26107695/move-multiple-links-in-controlgroup-up-or-down-using-jquery-mobile