# Move multiple links in controlgroup up or down using JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

This is a follow-up question on my previous question ([Controlgroup: 3 buttons horizontal, multiple rows on JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088729/controlgroup-3-buttons-horizontal-multiple-rows-on-jquery-mobile)) which was nicely answered.

I now have multiple 'controls' vertically and each control is made of 4 links with images horizontally.
One of the images is to move down. When this image button/link is pressed the whole control of 4 links should move 1 down.

I've been using append, prepend, after, before but nothing seems to work.

I have updated my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/houtq5ku/1/), it will create 4 controls. When the button with the down error is pressed, the whole block should move down.

```
// Check if not already at the end:  
if (layerVisibleButton.length > 0) {
    // TODO: How to continue?
}
```

Comment: Interesting, yet a bit tricky to implement. Adding extra class _might_ lead to a solution. However, since you're creating them dynamically, classes wouldn't be so handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/), [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/), [`.prevUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevuntil/), [`.addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addback/), [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/), [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) and [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

1. `$(this).nextAll(".ui-last-child").eq(1)`

   Check if there is a set of buttons after the current set.
2. `$(this).prevUntil(".ui-last-child").addBack()`

   Get all buttons in the same row of the *down* button and `.addBack()` *down* button to jQuery collection object. Now we have three buttons.
3. `$(this).next(".ui-last-child")`

   Next button. Now we have collected four buttons (all of them) but still we need to *merge* them into one object.
4. `prevBtns.add(nextBtn)`

   Merge all buttons into one object/variable.
5. `moveAfter.after(setBtns)`

   Move/append all buttons after the row below current set of buttons.

```js
$("#layercontrol").on("click", ".down", function () {
    var moveAfter = $(this).nextAll(".ui-last-child").eq(1);
    if (moveAfter.length > 0) {
        var prevBtns = $(this).prevUntil(".ui-last-child").addBack(),
            nextBtn = $(this).next(".ui-last-child"),
            setBtns = prevBtns.add(nextBtn);
            moveAfter.after(setBtns);
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/w7gr54j9/)**

Comment: Thanks @Omar. Not only works your demo as requested, the explanation is also very valuable.

Comment: @PaulMeems you're welcome :) I'm working on "up arrow" btw. I'll notify you once I get it working as it's rather complicated :)

Comment: @PaulMeems I've updated the same demo, now both up and down buttons work.